# How can I make content blocks that fill 50% of the viewport?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have a design which uses content blocks that are each 50% of the viewport. As you scroll down, more 50% high blocks appear.

I am having difficulty implementing this while keeping the design responsive to other elements. I had a method of designing it, however a footer is incompatible with that method.

This is my previous design: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zj0of786/1/). As you can see, the `<main>` is resized to 100% of the viewport, the rest of the content becoming overflow. However, this fails when a footer is added, since it is placed directly after the viewport and obstructs the content.

**HTML:**

```
<main>
  <section>
    <p>
      Integer accumsan magna vitae velit lobortis blandit. Integer et ante augue. Ut ut vehicula ante. Donec eget finibus nibh. Aliquam sit amet ligula non ipsum facilisis efficitur. Mauris laoreet non diam sit amet imperdiet. Pellentesque eu risus luctus,
      accumsan dolor tempor, pellentesque massa. Pellentesque scelerisque fringilla tellus, nec commodo lorem commodo non.
    </p>
  </section>
  <section>
    <p>
      Integer accumsan magna vitae velit lobortis blandit. Integer et ante augue. Ut ut vehicula ante. Donec eget finibus nibh. Aliquam sit amet ligula non ipsum facilisis efficitur. Mauris laoreet non diam sit amet imperdiet. Pellentesque eu risus luctus,
      accumsan dolor tempor, pellentesque massa. Pellentesque scelerisque fringilla tellus, nec commodo lorem commodo non.
    </p>
  </section>
  <section>
    <p>
      Integer accumsan magna vitae velit lobortis blandit. Integer et ante augue. Ut ut vehicula ante. Donec eget finibus nibh. Aliquam sit amet ligula non ipsum facilisis efficitur. Mauris laoreet non diam sit amet imperdiet. Pellentesque eu risus luctus,
      accumsan dolor tempor, pellentesque massa. Pellentesque scelerisque fringilla tellus, nec commodo lorem commodo non.
    </p>
  </section>
  <section>
    <p>
      Integer accumsan magna vitae velit lobortis blandit. Integer et ante augue. Ut ut vehicula ante. Donec eget finibus nibh. Aliquam sit amet ligula non ipsum facilisis efficitur. Mauris laoreet non diam sit amet imperdiet. Pellentesque eu risus luctus,
      accumsan dolor tempor, pellentesque massa. Pellentesque scelerisque fringilla tellus, nec commodo lorem commodo non.
    </p>
  </section>
</main>
<footer>
</footer>
```

**CSS:**

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}

body,
html {
  height: 100%
}

main {
  height:100%
}

section:nth-child(even) {
  background: red
}

section:nth-child(odd) {
  background: green
}

section {
  height: 50%;
}
footer{
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  position:relative;
  height:50%;
}
```

How can I either:

- Modify my previous design to accomodate a footer

or

- Change my design so that `<main>` does not use overflow, and stretches to accommodate the `<section>` elements, retaining their 50% of the viewport. (This is probably the more likely option, but I can't figure out how to do this).

Appreciate any help! I'm stuck. I'm willing to use Javascript or Jquery, but I'd prefer to keep it to HTML and CSS (except maybe for browser fallbacks).

Update: VH units seem to work well, but are not supported in IE8 or earlier. Anyone have input on how to design a fallback?

Comment: Maybe you could use `vh` units instead https://jsfiddle.net/zj0of786/3/

Comment: @Nenad
Yes, vh value is so much better, its like the flexbox equivalent to float, clearfix etc:-)
Setting css height in px or % can lead to all kinds of issues, while vh is very clear and leaves no room for interpretation.
I have only learne dof it when i tried to do a background attachment:fixed site. For VH to work properly, html and body should be 100vh as well, or at very least 100%.

Comment: First I've learned of this, thanks. Looks like its not supported in IE8 though, anyone have fallback ideas?

Answer (score 1):

```
element{
height:50vh;
}
```

There is also a flexbox solution for this.
I am not so sure setting height like that to .main is ideal.
use 100vh on both instead.

Comment: First I've learned of this! Thank you. While checking browser support, it's not supported in IE8 or earlier. If anyone has any input on how to design a fallback, that would be great!

Comment: I am not sure this will work in the oldest IEs, but check this out:
http://codepen.io/damianocel/pen/dYKxgW

Set line 25 to "top:0;"
Keep in mind its a transparent picture, so the result might look bit misleading.